# Populate array based on JSON object mapping

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a requirement where I need to populate array based on mapping of JSON object.
For e.g:
Suppose I have JSON object as shown below:

```
let columns = { 'name' :'value', 'id' : 1, 'age': 15}
```

And I want to create an array having value as shown below:

```
var values = [1, 15, value]; // id, age, name
```

I was able to create array of array as shown below:

```js
var data = new Array();
var output = new Array();
let columns = [
{ 'name' :'value', 'id' : 1, 'age': 15},
{ 'name' :'value1', 'id' : 2, 'age': 18}
];

for(let i=0;i< columns.length; i++) {
    for (let variable in columns[i]) {
      data.push(columns[i][variable]);
    }
    output.push(data);
    data = new Array();
  }
  
  console.log(output);
```

I am struggling to push value to array in order which I need. I tried by creating a mapping object but no success so far. Please let me know possible solution.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the solution is there any way by which I can define the map function arguments and json object in variable. And replace it. Something like shown below:

```
let mapping {
columns : '{name, id, age}',
mapping : '[id, age, name]'
}
const result = columns.map((mapping.columns) => mapping.mapping);
```

Comment: "I am struggling to push value to array in order which I need", if u know order just push them in order! if u dont know order how u want sort them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map()` method with ES6 parameter destructuring and add properties to array in order you want.

```js
let columns = [{ 'name' :'value', 'id' : 1, 'age': 15},{ 'name' :'value1', 'id' : 2, 'age': 18}];

const result = columns.map(({name, id, age}) => [id, age, name]);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Seems perfect solution. Please look at edited question.

Comment: @Tavish Aggarwal Order of properties in object is not guaranteed, so what is your logic or criteria for order of properties here?

Comment: Mapping object. For eg:
`var mapping = { 'id' : 'id', 'emp_age' : 'age', 'user_name' : 'name' }`. So user_name maps to name and should come in second place.

Comment: I got it thanks!. But I have one question. I won't be able to declare array like `var test = [id, age, name];` and object. Is there any way to make it generic so that I can map any columns the way I want?

Comment: You need to define some rules how you are going to identify keys so you can then put them in array in order you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can also remove the inner for loop and read data with the column names (or the JSON field names), So it becomes as follows.

```js
var data = new Array();
var output = new Array();
let columns = [
{ 'name' :'value', 'id' : 1, 'age': 15},
{ 'name' :'value1', 'id' : 2, 'age': 18}
];

for(let i=0;i< columns.length; i++) {
   data.push(columns[i]['id']);
   data.push(columns[i]['age']);
   data.push(columns[i]['name']);
    output.push(data);
    data = new Array();
  }
  
  console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Object.values()` to get the every values from the `object`

```js
  
var output = new Array();
let columns = [
{ 'name' :'value', 'id' : 1, 'age': 15},
{ 'name' :'value1', 'id' : 2, 'age': 18}
];
 output = columns.map(item => Object.values(item))
  
  console.log(output);
```